# How can I upload files in Tip-Tap editor for React?

Tags: reactjs, editor, tiptap

I'm using tip-tap editor for the purpose of making a messaging feature required in a project I'm working. Everything seems to work in my favor except for the fact that there is no native option that I can find to upload files in it other than images.

Is it even possible to upload files in Tip-Tap editor for react?

Comment: I would say it is possible but would require effort from your side to support this via a custom extension.

Answer (score 2):

Since `tiptap` does not have support for `files` and what you will use it for is `messaging`, I share with you a solution that I implemented for a `chat`.

It consists of adding a `button` to upload the files in this way:
[Ejemplo del botón](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2txFo.png)

then the button can be called using the shortcuts offered by the editor

```js
const EventHandler = Extension.create({
  name: "eventHandler",

  addProseMirrorPlugins() {
    return [
      new Plugin({
        key: new PluginKey("eventHandler"),
        props: {
          handleKeyDown: (view, event) => {
            if (event.metaKey || event.ctrlKey) {
              // Open files
              if (event.key === "o") {
                event.preventDefault();
                let plusMenuFile = document.getElementById("plus-menu-tools-item-file");
                if (plusMenuFile) {
                  plusMenuFile.click();
                } else {
                  document.getElementById("MediaFilesText-input-file").click();
                }
              }
              // ...
            }
          }
        }
      })
    ];
  }
});

const editor = useEditor({
   extensions: [
      StarterKit,
      EventHandler,
      //...
   ]
});
```

Here then I leave the example of how I use it in the tiptap editor: https://codesandbox.io/s/adoring-grothendieck-fu82ju

Comment: How can we make it to show the files in the message itself and not only in the toolbar?

Answer (score 1):

`tiptap editor` doesn't support `files` only `images`, and on fast search there's no third party extensions to do it ether.